# How to get around waiting for a new page to load and selecting an id that wasn't visible on the previous page

Tags: javascript, dom, scripting, window, onload

I'm trying to create a script for a browser game I'm playing using the scripty extension for chrome with javascript.

When I simulate a button click, I'm pretty sure it's bringing up a new page to submit the command.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("target-input-field target-input-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-input")[0].value = "433|539"; 
document.getElementById("unit_input_sword").value = "2";
document.getElementById("unit_input_spear").value = "2";
```

selecting unit count and attack location, this works ^

the problem is after I simulate the target_attack click, it brings up a new page and I cant find the id. I was thinking I could use window.onload() for this but I just haven't managed to get it to work, or an async await function, which again I can't get to work.

The below code is the last of what I was trying to get work before I've now give up and ask for help.

```
const submit = async function () {
  return document.getElementById("target_attack").click();
};

submit().then(function() {

        document.getElementById("troop_confirm_submit").click();    
 });
```

Expecting after the target_attack click is triggered, the troop_confirm_submit get's triggered right after.